How can I get HMR working with Radicle (Sage) inside DDEV?
Using DDEV to develop a WordPress site locally using Radicle. I'm having issues getting the Live Reload working using bud from within the DDEV container with proper URL's and HTTPS. Any ideas?
I've tried exposing ports using DDEV's additional_ports, web_extra_exposed_ports and a seperate ddev composer file.

I've managed to get this working properly for Radicle, but this should also work for Sage 10 with minor modifications if any.
In DDEV's .ddev/config.yaml, add web_extra_exposed_ports:
web_extra_exposed_ports:
  - name: radicle
    container_port: 4000
    http_port: 3999
    https_port: 4000

Then in the bud.config.ts file I changed serve() to only include the port and then changed the proxy URL to a ENV variable and added setPublicUrl() to make sure all URL's are correct.
.serve(4000)
.proxy(bud.env.get('WP_HOME'))
.setPublicUrl(bud.env.get('WP_HOME') + ':4000')

The one oddity was that I couldn't use a variable for my .env file's WP_SITEURL so for the URL's in my .env I have:
WP_HOME='https://project.ddev.site'
WP_SITEURL='https://project.ddev.site/wp'

